# Redraw widgets with update

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Let's say I have a button. In it's constructor I use variables to feed the values(before running I set some default values to these variables), so later they can be changed and within the program the look of the GUI can be modified. What I need is to update the widgets whenever I change these values.
For example I have some options to change a certain color, I press the button it calls a certain command defined in the constructor, changes the color variable and after that, it needs to be updated. Here it says the update() redraws widgets as needed. How do I tell it I need the widgets to be redrawn ?
http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm
I might be mistaken on what the redrawing actually means. In any case I need it to update with the new values. I have a quite dumb solution for this, that is destroying everything and rebuilding it. I feel like there is a smarter way of doing things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All widgets have a `configure` method which can be called to change any of its attributes. All you have to do is keep a reference to the widget(s), and call the method:

```
def update_the_widgets():
    the_label.configure(background="red")

a_button = tk.Button(..., command=update_the_widgets)
the_label = tk.Label(..., background="green")
```

This is much easier if you use an object oriented style of coding. Otherwise these references need to be global variables.

When your GUI is properly coded you should almost never need to call `update`.

Comment: ah yes, what I forgot was I dont use those references as "a_button", since I have a lot of widgets. I just remembered about control variables such as StringVar() .I know they work for text, but do they work for other stuff like foreground or size or anything else ?

Comment: I guess I can keep a reference and use exec(), for loops and the list of widgets to quickly update them, thanks.

Comment: @JozefMéry: there should never ever be a need to use `exec` when working with Tkinter widgets. If you feel you have to, you're probably doing something wrong. You don't need one variable per widget; you can keep a list or dictionary of widgets and iterate over then just like you can any other objects.

Comment: List of widgets ... I should have known earlier... Thanks